# How to display specific tags on top of a page?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello to you dear developper community !

I am working on my blog, trying to sort things out. I am trying to find a way to display only some tags in labels, on top of specifics pages, so that my visitors can easily see what they are interested in.

I already use a widget in my sidebar for all the tags. The idea would be to display maybe 4 to 5 of them on top of my pages, according to the topic.

For instance, on "my travels", for the "France" section, I would like to display "Discovery", "Hiking", "Food", "Vidéos", "Photos".

[What I would like to do, see in black labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZZK.jpg)
Thanks a lot for your help !!
Lily

Answer (score 0):

```css
.topLabel {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topLabel:hover {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<a class="topLabel">Hiking</a>
<a class="topLabel">Food</a>
<a class="topLabel">Photos</a>
<a class="topLabel">Videos</a>
<a class="topLabel">Discovery</a>
```

maybe this helps you.`

Answer (score 0):

Access the post tags using `get_the_tags()`

```
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
if ($post_tags) {
  foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```